Data transformation from GCS Krasovsky to GCS Russia 2011
I have data in the coordinate system Krasovsky_1940_Transverse_Mercator. I need to convert it to the GCS_Russia_2011 system. But I have difficulty choosing a transformation method. I'm using the Project tool and ArcGIS 10.8.


Disclosure: I work for Esri on the Esri projection engine which includes the predefined coordinate reference systems and transformations.
I would like to help you, but unfortunately, I cannot. It looks like you have ArcGIS Desktop (you've tagged it 10.8, is that correct?). The already defined set of transformations for Russia doesn't include any from Krasovsky 1940. Krasovsky 1940 is an ellipsoid (spheroid) that is used by older Russian and Soviet geographic coordinate reference systems. It might be Pulkovo 1942 or Pulkovo 1995. If data is using GRID files, and thus the ArcInfo Workstation-style prj.adf files, that might be converted in Desktop to "Krasovsky 1940".
We do have transformations for PZ90 and the GOST system, but the transformation names don't match what you have. They all look custom-built to me. If you work in an agency or company large enough, they might have defined and installed by a GIS administrator.
